# Defining a class name Money

Tags: java

I am stuck with the add/subtract methods for Defining a class named Money whose objects represent amounts of US money.  The class should have 2 instance variables of type int for the dollars and cents in the amount of money.  Include a constructor with 2 parameters of type int for dollars and cents, one with one constructor of type int for an amount of dollars with zero cents and a no-argument constructor. Include the methods add and minus for addition and subtraction of amounts of money, and return a value of type Money.  Include a reasonable set of accessor and mutator methods as well as the methods equals and toString.

Again, I am stuck on the add/minus part, just cannot nail it down.  Plus the equals part is a bit confusing.  Yes this is homework.  I am trying my best but need a bit of a push.

Please take a look....

```
public class Money {

    private static  int dollars;
    private static int cents;

    public Money()
    {

    }

    public Money(int dollars, int cents)
    {
        this.dollars = dollars;
        this.cents = cents;
    }

    public Money(int dollars)
    {
        this.dollars = dollars;
    }



    public int getDollars() {
        return dollars;
    }

    public void setDollars(int dollars) {
        this.dollars = dollars;
    }

    public int getCents() {
        return cents;
    }

    public void setCents(int cents) {
        this.cents = cents;
    }


    public static Money add(Money m1, Money m2)
    {
        int cash = m1.dollars + m2.dollars;
        int change = m1.cents + m2.cents;
        return new Money(dollars, cents);


    }

    public static int MinusMoney(int m3, int m4)
    {
        return (m3-m4);
    }
    public boolean equals(double YourMoney)
    {
        boolean result;
        if (YourMoney > 0)
        {
            dollars += cents;
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;


    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ("$" + getDollars() + "." + getCents());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Money MyMoney = new Money(2,30);

        System.out.println("You have " + MyMoney.toString());

        Money MyMoney1 = new Money(2,30);
        Money MyMoney2 = new Money(3,10);

        System.out.println("You now have " + Money.add(MyMoney1, MyMoney2));

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't declare your fields `static`!!

Comment: in the add method, if the sum of cent is >100 as it can be, cash should be cash + 1; cent = cent - 100;

Comment: Your `add()` method doesn't carry-over, e.g. adding `1.75` and `2.75` should yield `4.50`, but will yield `3.150`. Your `MinusMoney` is entirely wrong (bad name, parameter types, return type, ...). Remove it. It should be fairly similar to the `add()` method.

Comment: Here's an idea, rather then working in dollars and cents, work only in cents, it will make the addition and subtraction simpler and you can return a "formatted" version in dollars.cents when you need

Comment: I noticed the static part too and took it off.

Comment: @MadProgrammer seems the assignment specifically asked for dollar and cent variables in the class.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements state that operations on the object (such as add and subtract) return a new instance rather than changing the current one. Thus:

```
class Money {
    private int dollars;
    private int cents;

    public Money(int dollars, int cents) {
        if (dollars < 0 || cents < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative dollars or cents");
        this.dollars = dollars;
        this.cents = cents;
    }

    public Money add(Money other) {
        int cents = this.cents + other.cents;
        return new Money(this.dollars + other.dollars + cents / 100, cents % 100);
    }
}
```

With respect to `equals`, this would normally be defined to override `Object.equals` which means that it needs to accept an `Object` not a `double`:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return other != null && other.getClass() == Money.class
        && this.dollars == (Money)other.dollars
        && this.cents == (Money)other.cents;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue with carry-over. Requirement *"Include a reasonable set of accessor and **mutator** methods"* would imply that it is not supposed to be immutable.

Comment: @Andreas I added carry-over code. I'll remove the immutability to avoid confusion.

Comment: Good. Though I do agree that requiring `add()` to return a new instance would make more sense for an immutable implementation. If class is mutable, it'd make more sense (to me at least) to have it update the object. But, it's an assignment. They don't always make sense, since they're used to test simple coding skills at that stage.

Comment: @Andreas I agree it'd make more sense as an immutable class - especially as it's really just a complex data type with minimal logic: an obvious candidate for immutability But, as you say, it's an assignment...

Comment: Ya, I tried the boolean equals section in my code and it came up with errors in the this.dollars and this.cents lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of an update since posting.  I figured out the add/minus and it works.  Thank you for the equals portion, but a question in there arises.

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return other != null && other.getClass() == Money.class
        && this.dollars == (Money)other.dollars
        && this.cents == (Money)other.cents
```

the section about other.getClass()...Are you referring to the Money Class or is this something that I need to add more methods?

```
public class Money {

    private int dollars;
    private int cents;

    public Money()
    {

    }

    public Money(int dollars, int cents)
    {
        this.dollars = dollars;
        this.cents = cents;
    }

    public Money(int dollars)
    {
        this.dollars = dollars;
    }



    public int getDollars() {
        return dollars;
    }

    public void setDollars(int dollars) {
        this.dollars = dollars;
    }

    public int getCents() {
        return cents;
    }

    public void setCents(int cents) {
        this.cents = cents;
    }

    public static Money add(Money m1, Money m2)
    {
        int dollars1 = m1.getDollars();
        int dollars2 = m2.getDollars();
        int cents1 = m1.getCents();
        int cents2 = m2.getCents();

        int sumDollars = dollars1 + dollars2;
        int sumCents = cents1 + cents2;

        if(sumCents > 100)
        {
            sumDollars = sumDollars +1;
            sumCents = sumCents - 100;
        }
        Money output = new Money(sumDollars, sumCents);
        return output;


    }

    public static Money minus(Money m1, Money m2)
    {
        int dollars1 = m1.getDollars();
        int dollars2 = m2.getDollars();
        int cents1 = m1.getCents();
        int cents2 = m2.getCents();

        int sumDollars = dollars1 - dollars2;
        int sumCents = cents1 - cents2;

        if(sumCents > 100)
        {
            sumDollars = sumDollars +1;
            sumCents = sumCents - 100;
        }
        Money output = new Money(sumDollars, sumCents);
        return output;


    }
    public boolean equals(double YourMoney)
    {
        boolean result;
        if (YourMoney > 0)
        {
            dollars += cents;
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
    return ("$" + getDollars() + "." + getCents());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Money MyMoney = new Money(2,30);

        System.out.println("You have " + MyMoney.toString());

        Money MyMoney1 = new Money(12,30);
        Money MyMoney2 = new Money(7,10);

        System.out.println("You now have " + Money.minus(MyMoney1, MyMoney2));

}

}
```

Comment: `getClass` is a method of `Object` which is a class that all other classes automatically extend. It returns the class of the object. Also note that it's bad practice on SO to post an answer as a question. Better to append a comment to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You are making things complicated by using 2 attributes one for dollar and one for cent . You rather simply covert dollar to cent and pass cents instead or convert dollar to cent in method itself.Then use method to perform calculation easily.
You can do it by

```
totalcents1= dollar1*100 +cent1;
totalcents2= dollar2*100 + cent2;
//for add
return totalcents1+totalcents2;
//for substract do check which is greater
return totalcents1-totalcents2;
```

reverse process for cent to dollar

Comment: Please up vote if you are helped with my answer. When you get privilege of it.